# Install / upgrade all organization / scope (@angular) dependencies in package.json to same version

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I currently have this in dependencies in package.json:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
```

is there some command line option, *to bump all of them to v5.2.0*?

Something like this:

```
npm install -S @angular/*@5.2.0  # not real, just a guess
```

Because of version mismatch, there are some errors, I need them to all be at 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with yarn using this command

```
yarn upgrade --scope @angular
```

More info is here

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade#toc-yarn-upgrade-scope-s-scope-latest-pattern

hope it helps

Comment: cool! is there a way to do that without yarn? also, how do you pick a version? maybe this: `yarn upgrade --scope @angular@5.2.0` ?

Comment: yes a little difference yarn upgrade --scope @angular/5.2.0 . I haven't heard a native solution using npm

Comment: yeah I am hesitant to commit to using Yarn..I have mastered using NPM, and with Yarn I am getting permissions issues that I have already solved with NPM.

Comment: Yeah, I upvoted, but using `yarn upgrade --scope @angular/5.2.0` didn't work, with and without sudo. That's a shame.